# Lift style views in a PHP framework

Tags: php, templates, lift

just wondering if a PHP web framework or templating engine exists, that uses the [clean view philosophy](http://wiki.liftweb.net/index.php?title=Lift_View_First) used in [Lift](http://liftweb.net/), the Scala webframework.

In short the clean view philosophy, is that there should be zero code in the views. And that the view should be valid HTML.

I would like to replace a typical piece of PHP code like this:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($addressbook as $name):?>
    <li><?=$name?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

With a html tag only template like this:

```
<ul>
    <framework:AddressBookView.listNames>
        <li:name />
    </framework:AddressBookView.listNames>
</ul>
```

Which would call the *listNames* method on the *AddressBookView* class. The *listNames* method would then take care of repeatedly binding the names from the AddressBook names to the *<li:name />* tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPTAL is just such a template engine...

http://phptal.org/